# Rounding of numeric value in postgres

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL I am using the function `round` but it does not return `decimal` point. See the example

```
select round(10.65)
```

returns 11, but actually I need 11.00.

I also tried

```
select round(10.65, 2)
```

and it returns 10.65.

How to return the numeric value with two decimal points in PostgreSQL?

I want the output like this `select round(10.65)` should return `11.00`. How to make it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should do this:

```
 select round(round(10.65),2);
```